# Unable to deploy JavaFX application to Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, javafx, deployment, raspberry-pi

I want to deploy my javafx application on a raspberry pi from within IntelliJ (making debugging easier as well). For this purpose I installed the following plugin for embedded linux development: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7738-embedded-linux-jvm-debugger-raspberry-pi-beaglebone-black-intel-galileo-ii-and-several-other-iot-devices-

I can connect to my Pi just fine. Deployment also works fine. However, once the following command is executed, something goes wrong:

`Executing Command :sudo java -Dprism.verbose=true -cp classes:lib/'*' runnable.MainApp`

A load of class files show up (such as `classes/mypackage/MyClass.class`), and eventually, I get the following stack-trace, and I'm not sure what to make of it.
The kernel version of the Pi is: `Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`

```
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
```

And right after I get the following:

```
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline

GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/pi/IdeaProjects/user_interface/arm/libprism_sw.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$472(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Have you installed JavaFX for ARM? If so which SDK versions (JDK and JavaFX) are you using? Also, are you trying to use frame buffer?

Comment: I don't think so. On my own machine I'm using JDK 1.8.0_121. How would I install JavaFX for ARM? I've head Oracle dropped support recently however, I'm not sure how big of an issue that is.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284239/javafx-ensemble-on-raspberry-pi/28284736#28284736) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961054/can-javafx-be-used-on-raspberry-pi), and make sure you have the latest JavaFX SDK for ARM from [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/get/)